# How to achieve 2 rows + 1 column grid layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to come up with simple way of creating a grid like container that has 2 columns, one column split up into 2 rows and the other column full height. Here's an image illustrating what I'm after.

[image]

It looks a bit complicated but I was thinking about using a responsive grid system to get this to look the way I want. I've tried various grid layouts and none seem to be able to mimic what I'm after, mainly the right column being full height and the left column being split into two.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I tried bootstrap but it's not really responsive enough for this I feel. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap is certainly adequate for something so simple. It may be overkill for it, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bootstrap, here's an example structure. Just about any responsive grid will be similar. If you want to write your own grid, use your browser's document inspector to check out what Bootstrap does for the row and column elements.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 pink"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 green"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2w2L8auq/)**

---

If you want something that fills the screen vertically (but may need internal scrollbars to contain your content), this would do:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
#one {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#two {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
}
#three {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/okqafz5w/)**

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Both examples are a great help. The issue I'm running into using the second example is that the entire image must be visible at all times. I quickly threw this together: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvZPpP  - as the width of the window increases, portions of the image get cut off. Ideally the image would control the height of the entire container because 100% of the image height would be visible at all times.

Comment: In the modern, responsive web you can't usually achieve that unless you have space around the image. As a photographer I'd argue that you don't need to show every part of that image. Its story is told just as it is in your demo. I'd be happy with that. Good luck.

Comment: It's a small part of many different sections in a row, some similarly coded so there is space for it, I'd imagine. Would putting it in a container and setting a container height help this at all? Again I really appreciate your help!